Why there is a horizontal scroll on mobile
If you shorten the width of the window or check on mobile, there is a horizontal scroll, breaking the layout.
Live Link
I believe most probably navigation is causing this, but no clue how. Tried everything from setting width/max-width to 100%, overflow: hidden, etc.
Can someone help how to resolve this?

So it seems to be caused by padding in these 2 places
#header-content .container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: end;
    text-align: right;
    position: relative;
/*  padding: 5rem; */
}

#about-content .container {
/*  padding: 3rem 5rem; */
}

One tip you could use to find the place that is overflowing is to put this code at the top of your file
* {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

This will add an red outline to every object so you can see an overflow quicker

#about {
    overflow-x: clip;
}

Will fix your issue. It's caused by your container padding (5rem horizontal), which is quite a lot for a mobile view because although it's a relative unit, it's not relative to viewport width. You could use something like padding: 3rem clamp(1rem, 5vw, 5rem); instead so that the padding is responsive.
